# Adding a delay to to a form scroller

Tags: javascript, forms, settimeout

I am using http://tympanus.net/codrops/2014/07/30/fullscreen-form-interface/ to build a form - I want a delay before the page scrolls down after the click event.

I've been trying to achieve this using setTimeout but have been struggling.

For example I thought this would work:

```
    // show next field
    setTimeout(function() {
        this.ctrlContinue.addEventListener( 'click', function() {
            self._nextField(); 
        } );
    }, 1000);
```

You can see the full code at https://github.com/codrops/FullscreenForm/blob/master/js/fullscreenForm.js

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This should work, you should set timeout after click event not before.

```
this.ctrlContinue.addEventListener( 'click', function() {
    setTimeout(function() {  
        self._nextField(); 
    }, 1000);
});
```

Comment: can u please create jsfiddle. so i can help you